# Elixir complex pattern matching order

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I'm reading the great [Joy of Elixir](https://joyofelixir.com/6-pattern-matching/) and I'm trying to wrap my head around the order of operations in the pattern matching example.

I've got the list

```
crew = [  
    %{name: "mal", age: 40},
    %{name: "zoey", age: 36},
]
```

Now I can use pattern matching to take the first element of the list, and assign the name to a different variable like

```
[first = %{name: first_name} | others] = crew
```

I understand that the first element in `crew` was assigned to `first` and that the `name` of `first` was assigned to `first_name`:

```
iex> first
%{age: 40, name: "mal"}
iex> first_name
"mal"
```

According to the examples I can also assign the name to another variable from right-to-left:

```
%{name: first_name2} = first
```

But the same fails when I try it from left-to-right:

```
iex> first = %{name: first_name3}
** (CompileError) iex:33: undefined function first_name3/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1355: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

**My question is: Why is left-to-right assignment OK within list matching, but fails outside of list matching?**

Comment: Variable has to be already assigned on the right side.

Comment: @denis.peplin so why is this not the case within `[first = %{name: first_name} | others] = crew`? `first_name` is on the right side of `first`

Comment: `crew` provides the data here

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/54845967/1225617

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right side of `=` (match operator) is evaluated first. In the expression

```
 first = %{name: first_name3}
```

It tries to get the value of `first_name3`, but there's no `first_name3` in the scope.

For the expression

```
[first = %{name: first_name} | others] = crew
```

you can think of it as

```
[first = %{name: first_name} = %{age: 40, name: "mal"} | others] = crew
```

or

```
others = tl(crew)
head = hd(crew)
first = %{name: first_name} = head
```

Here's another example:

`x = "foo"` binds the variable `x` to string `"foo"` (because `x` is unbound at first). Now that `x` has been bound
  to `"foo"`, `"foo" = x` is also a valid expression since `"foo"` matches `x`.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the way elixir evaluates a sequence. When you start up your iex your environment will be empty. When you type in first = %{name: first_name3} It will start by evaluating the right hand side. Inside of the actual map you are trying to associate the key "name" to the variable first_name3. If first_name3 does not exist in your environment the expression will fail to evaluate and you will get the undefined function error.

this should work:

```
first_name3 = "John"
first = %{name: first_name3}
```

Comment: So I'm wrong in thinking that `first = %{name: first_name} ` within `[first = %{name: first_name} | others] = crew` is left to right?